# Array not filling out like I'm expecting it to

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that's supposed to take in an array of arrays, and split it into an array of arrays of 100 items each. The problem is that when I execute it, in this case, passing it 1137 items, the return array, has 12 arrays, all empty except for the last one.

Here's the code:

```
$names_to_fetch_from_twitter = array (
    array('screen_name' => 'acme', 'profiles_rownum' => 1, 'screen_name_rownum' => 1),
    array('screen_name' => 'acme1', 'profiles_rownum' => 2, 'screen_name_rownum' => 2),
    array('screen_name' => 'acme2', 'profiles_rownum' => 3, 'screen_name_rownum' => 3),
    array('screen_name' => 'acme3', 'profiles_rownum' => 4, 'screen_name_rownum' => 4),
    array('screen_name' => 'acme4', 'profiles_rownum' => 5, 'screen_name_rownum' => 5)
        );

$names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized = split_into_blokcs_of_3 ($names_to_fetch_from_twitter);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized);
echo '</pre>';

function split_into_blokcs_of_3 ($names_to_fetch_from_twitter)
{
    $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized = array();
    $count = 1;
    $screen_names = array();
    $profiles_row_nums = array();
    $screen_name_rownums = array();
    foreach ($names_to_fetch_from_twitter as $name_to_fetch_from_twitter) {
        $screen_names[] = $name_to_fetch_from_twitter['screen_name'];
        $profiles_row_nums[] = $name_to_fetch_from_twitter['profiles_rownum'];
        $screen_name_rownums[] = $name_to_fetch_from_twitter['screen_name_rownum'];
        $count++;
        if ($count > 3) {
            $count = 1;
            $screen_names = array();
            $profiles_row_nums = array();
            $screen_name_rownums = array();            
            $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized[] = 
                    package_into_array($screen_names,$profiles_row_nums,$screen_name_rownums,$names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized);
        }
    }
    if ($count > 1) {
        $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized[] = 
                package_into_array($screen_names,$profiles_row_nums,$screen_name_rownums,$names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized);
    }
    return $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized;
}

function package_into_array($screen_names,$profiles_row_nums,$screen_name_rownums,$names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized) 
{
    $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized[] = array (
        'screen_names' => implode (',',$screen_names),
        'profiles_row_nums' => $profiles_row_nums,
        'screen_name_rownums' => $screen_name_rownums
    );    
    return $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [screen_names] => 
                    [profiles_row_nums] => Array
                        (
                        )
                    [screen_name_rownums] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [screen_names] => 
                            [profiles_row_nums] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [screen_name_rownums] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [screen_names] => acme3,acme4
                    [profiles_row_nums] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4
                            [1] => 5
                        )
                    [screen_name_rownums] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4
                            [1] => 5
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

When I'm expecting the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [screen_names] => acme1,acme2,acme3
            [profiles_row_nums] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )    
            [screen_name_rownums] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3   
                )
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [screen_names] => acme4,acme5
            [profiles_row_nums] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )    
            [screen_name_rownums] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                ) 
        )      
)
```

Any ideas?

### Solution:

I had a couple of errors:

1. I was resetting the arrays before I included them in the master array
2. I was incrementing the array both in the main function and the helper function.

Here's the correct code:

```
function split_into_blokcs_of_3 ($names_to_fetch_from_twitter)
{
    $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized = array();
    $count = 1;
    $screen_names = array();
    $profiles_row_nums = array();
    $screen_name_rownums = array();
    foreach ($names_to_fetch_from_twitter as $name_to_fetch_from_twitter) {
        $screen_names[] = $name_to_fetch_from_twitter['screen_name'];
        $profiles_row_nums[] = $name_to_fetch_from_twitter['profiles_rownum'];
        $screen_name_rownums[] = $name_to_fetch_from_twitter['screen_name_rownum'];
        $count++;
        if ($count > 3) {   
            $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized = 
                    package_into_array($screen_names,$profiles_row_nums,$screen_name_rownums,$names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized);
            $count = 1;
            $screen_names = array();
            $profiles_row_nums = array();
            $screen_name_rownums = array();                     
        }
    }
    if ($count > 1) {
        $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized = 
                package_into_array($screen_names,$profiles_row_nums,$screen_name_rownums,$names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized);
    }
    return $names_to_fetch_from_twitter_organized;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be assuming that a new array is created inside of the if($count > 3) block.

You might try adding new array() there instead of just array but that should overwrite what was there previously.

Comment: new array? I am not familiar with this syntax. As far as I know, in PHP, you declare a new array by stating $var_array = array();

Comment: I think you're right. I was thinking that in just setting the variable to an array() that PHP might just link up a reference to the previous variable that was set to array() but after reading some more it doesn't look like that would happen.